# Symfony event addListener and variable Scope/State

Tags: php, scope, listener, mediator

I'm currently using sitl/curl-easy to make a multi-curl parallel requets, but I'm having some hard time with scope / state:

```
// Init queue of requests
$queue = new \cURL\RequestsQueue;
```

... init queue options

```
// Set function to be executed when request will be completed
$queue->addListener('complete', function (\cURL\Event $event) 
{
    $response = $event->response->getContent();

    // ugly :D, get the key from the object request
    $key = explode("&key=", array_values($event->request->getOptions()->toArray())[0])[1];

    // if response is not null, truncate it to use less space 
    if ($response != null){
        $response = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "", $response);
    }

    >>>>>>>> DON'T WORK, $banner_holder is declared on the top of the php page
    array_push($banner_holder, array("key"=> $key,"content"=>$response));
});
```

How to push the array of $key and $response outside the listener?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a closure function you will need to specify that you want to "use" the `$banner_holder` array like so

`$queue->addListener('complete', function (\cURL\Event $event) use ($banner_holder) {`

Comment: Great, being a java programmer and doing php messes with my head. Didn't knew that syntax.